# Arduino extract data from serial monitor

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, serial-port

I wrote a simple controller for my robot in Python and now I want to send the data over the serial monitor to the Arduino. I managed to send the values but now I want to know how I can extract the data from the monitor with the Arduino. My Python code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import serial
import time
import math

ArmLänge = 205

TextX = 10
TextY = 10
TextZ = 10

font = ("Courier New", 11)
sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=font)

ser = serial.Serial("COM6")
ser.flushInput()

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Forward Kinematics:", font=("Helvetica", 12)), sg.Text("              Inverse Kinematics:", font=("Helvetica", 12))],
    [sg.Text("X"), sg.Slider((0, 360), orientation='horizontal', key='SLIDER_X'), sg.Text("X"),sg.InputText(size=(10, 10), key="InputX")],
    [sg.Text("Y"), sg.Slider((0, 360), orientation='horizontal', key='SLIDER_Y'), sg.Text("Y"),sg.InputText(size=(10, 10), key="InputY")],
    [sg.Text("Z"), sg.Slider((0, 360), orientation='horizontal', key='SLIDER_Z'), sg.Text("Z"),sg.InputText(size=(10, 10), key="InputZ")],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Exit'), sg.Button("Move")],
]

window = sg.Window("Controller", layout, finalize=True)
window['SLIDER_X'].bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', ' Release')
window['SLIDER_Y'].bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', ' Release')
window['SLIDER_Z'].bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', ' Release')

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'SLIDER_X Release':
        print("X Value:", values["SLIDER_X"])
    elif event == 'SLIDER_Y Release':
        print("Y Value:", values["SLIDER_Y"])
    elif event == 'SLIDER_Z Release':
        print("Z Value:", values["SLIDER_Z"])
    #elif event == "Move":
        #print("IK X:", values['InputX'])
        #print("IK Y:", values['InputY'])
        #print("IK Z:", values['InputZ'])

    valX = int(values["SLIDER_X"]/2)
    valY = int(values["SLIDER_Y"]/2)
    valZ = int(values["SLIDER_Z"]/2)

    Data = [1,valX,valY,valZ]
    print(Data)
    ser.write(Data)

    if values['InputX'] >= str(1):
        x = float(values['InputX'])
        y = float(values['InputY'])
        z = float(values['InputZ'])

        h = round(math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2))
        joint2 = round(math.degrees(math.atan(y / x)))
        joint3 = round(math.degrees(math.acos((h / 2) / (ArmLänge / 2))))

        print("----Ergebnis:----")
        print("Höhe:", h)
        print("Joint2:", joint2,"°")
        print("Joint3:", joint3,"°")

        IKData = [2, h, joint2, joint3]
        print(IKData)
        ser.write(IKData)

window.close()
ser.close()
```

It may not be the best code but it works. I need to extract every number for example [1, 20, 45, 30]. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, where is your Arduino code? stack overflow don't write code for you, we need you to write your code with your best effort and if you can't solve the problem, post your code and we will help you to debug if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the data goes to Serial in this Format as String:

> [1,valX,valY,valZ]

After reading the data from Serial and converting the data line to String with String() function, you can assign the values to desired variables using `sscanf()` function.

The function works like this -

> sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...)

So, here it would work like this -

```
int data_val1, data_val2, data_val3;

sscanf(Your_SerialData_String, [1,%d,%d,%d], data_val1, data_val2, data_val3);
```